# Whenever I update custom hosted WCF services I get "could not be activated"?

Tags: c#, wcf

When ever I update WCF hosted services in local host directory, it gives me this error,

```
The requested service, 'https://server.myserver.com/fruit/fruitservice.svc' could not be activated. See the server's diagnostic trace logs for more information.
```

Now if I put back old files it work's fine, only lines I added to wcf service are,

```
var ts = new TraceSource("SampleUsageTraceSource");
  ts.TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Information, 0, "my information event");
```

or even `Throw new exception("ss");` doesn't let it be activated.

I update service by putting  .svc and dll file into directory.

I also Used SvcTraceViewer.exe but couldn't find related error or maybe I don't know what to look for in logs.

**Error in Event viewer**

> System.InvalidOperationException: The type 'nameOFSolution.ClassName,
>   nameOFSolution, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=3049540358034590', provided as the Service attribute
>   value in the ServiceHost directive, or provided in the configuration
>   element
>   system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/serviceActivations could
>   not be found.    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactory.CreateServiceHost(String
>   constructorString, Uri[] baseAddresses)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.CreateService(String
>   normalizedVirtualPath)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.ActivateService(String
>   normalizedVirtualPath)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String
>   normalizedVirtualPath)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>   at
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String
>   normalizedVirtualPath)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.EnsureServiceAvailableFast(String
>   relativeVirtualPath)

**This is what I added to web.config for svctraceviewer**

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true" />
    <sources>
            <source name="System.ServiceModel" 
                    switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing"
                    propagateActivity="true">
            <listeners>
               <add name="sdt" 
                   type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" 
                   initializeData= "SdrConfigExample.e2e" />
            </listeners>
         </source>
    </sources>
</system.diagnostics>
```

Comment: Did you define your `SampleUsageTraceSource` in your config file? If so, you should replace your config file as well.

Comment: @MaxS-Betclic please see updated question for what I have added to web.config

Comment: `SampleUsageTraceSource ` doesn't seem to be defined in your config file.

Comment: oh how can I do that, sorry am new to wcf :(

Comment: Have a look [there](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025(v=vs.110).aspx) and search for `user-defined`